# Cannot remote desktop into Windows Azure VM

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I am running a trial of Windows Azure and setup a simple Windows Virtual Machine. However, I do not seem to be able to use the Windows Remote Desktop connection to remote into the machine. What am I doing wrong? At first sight it does not seem to like my userID and password. But then I also cannot ping the VM address. I do not want to go through VS or any other tool, I like to do a simple remote desktop connection through the Windows RMD tool.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Can you check that port 3389 is open in your VM? This port is normally used by remote desktop? You can check this from Virtual machine->Endpoint section within new azure preview portal. if there is no port defined, you will have to create new one.

Comment: Will add this, but I dont think it explains why I cannot even ping the ip of my instance...

Comment: Also what internal port do you use when setting a new external endpoint port to 3389? The internal 3389 port is reserved...;-(

Comment: I actually already have a remote desktop port set when creating a new instance, 3389 internally, 63252 externally. But nothing works, what worries me the most is that i cannot even ping the vm.

Comment: How are you trying to remote desktop? by running mstsc command on your machine? or from azure portal -> Connect? In mstsc, you will have to follow format of <your VMURL>:63252 when connecting

Comment: from my windows machine. I start the remote desktop tool, enter my instance IP and port that was externally exposed: xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:yyyy

Comment: but I first like to resolve why I cannot ping my instance. How can I specify the port when using the "ping.exe" command in the dos shell within windows 7?

Comment: You mayhave to add rule for ICMP in your VM's firewall.. Go to Control Panel --> System and security --> Windows Firewall --> Advanced settings --> Inbound rules --> New rule --> custom rule

in Protocol and ports: Protocol: ICMPv4 
on the same panel go to customize, choose "Specific ICMP types", check the box "echo request"

Go to next... next... and save it.

Comment: thanks but this did not solve the problem. I am sure I can connect through remote desktop but I cannot get past the login, it refuses userID and password. I strongly assume the UserID is the hostname I specified for the instance, correct?

Comment: User id is Administrator for VM

Comment: Ha, it works. Just out of curiosity, where would I figure out that it was Administrator? And how can I change it? by the way, below was the response I got from MS after describing in detail what my problem was...

Comment: am happy to mark your responses as the correct answer if you want to put up an answer. You solved my problem, maybe its trivial but you really went the extra mile to help out, really appreciate your help (I upvoted your comments)

Comment: When you create VM, username is always administrator. You can create more uses after log in to that VM and going to use account section. Since this portal is in beta, it is not displayed anywhere. I am sure in final version, they will have more useful portal

Comment: hope so, right now it looks pretty bumpy to say the least. Is it MS's policy to block downloading and installing Google Chrome or Firefox to its VM instances? ;-) I did not manage to install either...

Comment: you can install without any issue. when downloading from IE, you have to change security policy of browser which is by default very strict and does not allow any downloading

Comment: ok thanks, locating the browser or any other standard windows component for that matter in this specific server instance was an adventure in itself ;-)

Comment: Does not work for me, Port 3389 is open but I cannot connect (using remmina).

Answer (score 4):

It could be that the port is blocked, Azure VMs default to port 52137, in your endpoint settings alter this to the regular port 3389 - this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Freddy, would u please confirm first if your Windows Azure Virtual Machine is running or not and this you can confirm by looking at Preview Portal. I have seen some cases when the VM does not start first time and you would need to restart it first time.

So if VM is not running then please start it from the portal directly or even if it shows  "Running" start please restart it again.

There are a few troubleshooting steps described below so please follow them:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesforWindows/thread/9c88a364-c3eb-41aa-a6b0-3ceae00491c2

If none of the above steps resolve your problem go ahead and report this problem to same forum and you will have direct assistance from Windows Azure Virtual Machine team.

Comment: @MattWolf This is the answer given almost 2 years back, and things have changed a lot. -ve voting an old answer depend on personal bad experience is not constructive.

Comment: not sure why someone deleted my comment on why I downvoted. Guiding someone to the MS forums in case one does not find an answer here on StackOverflow is bizarre to say the least. And yes, my VM was running...with all due respect but I would downvote such answer twice if I could, not just an answer to my own question, simply because the quality content is close to zero. It basically boils down to "hey, if you checked your instance is running then come to our forum for help".

Answer (score -1):

RDP to a new VM with the RDP "endpoint" setup does not work by default for security reasons.

You need to get the RDP certificate or the .RDP file from azure.

click on a running VM and click "Connect" in the control panel at the bottom, this will download the .RDP file that contains the certificate, enter user name and password and away you go.